# Gaussian Naive Bayes sensitive to feature scaling

Tags: normalization, naive-bayes

I'm using a GNB algorithm. As to my knowledge it should be insensitive to feature scaling. However, when I standardize (z-score) or normalize (min-max scaling) those of my features that have a very high range, its performance boosts by 10 - 15%. How can this be? I'm using the sklearn implementation.

Comment: Did you check that your train and test sets are scaled disjointly?